# bayesian structural time series - estimate state space model with bsts package

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian, kalman-filter, state-space

I have a question about the interpretation of some outputs of the CausalImpact package. This package uses the bayesian structural time series package bsts, which estimates a state space model using MCMC.

example:

```
 library(CausalImpact)
 set.seed(1)
 x1 <- 100 + arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.999), n = 100)
 y <- 1.2 * x1 + rnorm(100)
 y[71:100] <- y[71:100] + 10
 data <- cbind(y, x1)

 pre.period <- c(1, 70)
 post.period <- c(71, 100)

 impact <- CausalImpact(data, pre.period, post.period)
 #plot(impact)

 names(impact$model$bsts.model)
```

The example estimates a state space model with a local linear trend and a regression component. See output of the below command which shows the trend; x2 is the regression component.

```
 StateSizes(impact$model$bsts.model$state.specification)
```

My question concerns 2 elements of the bsts.model object: The final.state and the state contribution.

```
final.state<-data.frame(impact$model$bsts.model$final.state)
state.contribution<-data.frame(impact$model$bsts.model$state.contributions)
```

,where each row is for 1 iteration of the MCMC (1000 iterations were run).

What is the interpretation of these outputs?

Thank you

Comment: To check the source code of bsts may be helpful.  https://github.com/cran/bsts